# Windows XP Keeps Appending .txt Filetype To My PHP Files

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I've recently started using Windows XP.  I installed xaamp and wrote a test PHP script, but I can't run it because windows keeps chnaging the filetype by automatically appending .txt.  How can I stop this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What are you using to write your files? If you're using notepad, make sure to check the *"Save type as"* field to be *"All Files"* and then make sure to add the .php extenion manually in the *"File Name"* field.

Alternatively you can try to find another environment to work in. While there are tons of other lightweight options available, I am a big fan of [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). Using that you're able to get specific syntax highlighting along with a plethora of other features that may help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Before saving file, when save file dialog comes, choose All Files option from 'Save As type' menu. and give file name of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Notepad to edit the scripts?
If so, when saving, choose "Save as type" = "all files" first, then append the php extension within the file name.